# How do I add the option for "Project and External Dependencies" to my build path in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I've tried modifying the .classpath file directly but it doesn't seem to work.

[Missing Project and External dependencies option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMeDM.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is how Gradle build dependencies, as managed by the Buildship project, appear. You don't "add" it to a project. You are not missing anything.